# Show non zero values on SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

have a query on how to get all dates to show in my query on SQL server. I have tried to GENERATE_SERIES but was struggling on how to fit it in: code below on query.

```
WITH 
    cte_data AS (
        SELECT
            customer_id,
            FORMAT(event_time,'yyyy-MM') as _month,
            'eventtype1' AS source
        FROM Pay.Money
        UNION 
        SELECT
            customer_id,
            FORMAT(event_time,'yyyy-MM') as _month,
            'eventtype2' AS source
        FROM Pay.Send)

SELECT
    _month,
    COUNT(customer_id) AS active_customer
FROM(
    SELECT 
        customer_id,
        _month,
        _no
    FROM(    
        SELECT
            customer_id,
            _month,
            count(customer_id) AS _no
        FROM cte_data
        GROUP BY
            _month,
            customer_id)l
    WHERE _no>2)j
GROUP BY _month
```

My data that comes out shows what I want but I would like to show 0 values for months that have no data next to them

Currently data is

```
10-2021 5
12-2021 9
02-2022  2
```

What I would like

```
10-2021 5
11-2021 0
12-2021 9
01-2022 0
02-2022 2
```

Comment: Does your filter `WHERE _no>2` impact the result ? if yes, you should maybe remove the WHERE clause and use a `HAVING(COUNT(customer_id)) >= 0` just after your GROUP BY at then end

Comment: Are there a NULL values in your data? You can try to use ISNULL()

Comment: you can add another cte with  time series from MIN(_,Month) till MAX(_Month) and elft join it

Comment: You need to outer join to a calendar table. I suggest you google calendar table

Comment: A Calendar table would solve this easy, without the need for a CTE.

Comment: Please learn the significant difference between UNION and UNION ALL and the often significant negative performance effects the former can have.

Comment: Thanks all, I managed to sort this using left join on a calendar table and coalesce